# 'setConfigSettings(FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings!): Unit' is deprecated

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

After upgrading Firebase libraries to

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
```

and syncing Gradle, I got warning:

```
'setConfigSettings(FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings!): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
'setDeveloperModeEnabled(Boolean): FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
```

in these lines:

```
//Setting Developer Mode enabled to fast retrieve the values
firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .build())
```

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56019291/what-is-firebase-remote-config-developer-mode

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After reading [setConfigSettings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#setConfigSettings(com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings)) and [setDeveloperModeEnabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder.html#setDeveloperModeEnabled(boolean)) I changed the code to:

```
firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(3600L)
        .build())
```

After upgrading to `com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.0` the method [setDefaults](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#setDefaults(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) was also deprecated. Replace it with `setDefaultsAsync`.

On first run of an application `firebaseRemoteConfig` won't fetch data and will return *default values*. To get actual values and cache them see [Android Firebase Remote Config initial fetch does not return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898038/android-firebase-remote-config-initial-fetch-does-not-return-value).

Instead of `3600L` you can use time like `TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(12)` (as proposed by @ConcernedHobbit).

Comment: I had to add "new": firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(3600L).build());

Comment: @Michalsx, yes, for Java. Thanks!

Comment: @CoolMind how did you end up with "3600L" i was trying to find out what the right interval should be/ was before with developer mode set to enabled. All i could find inside the firebase code led me to believe it should be "0L" for dev mode but maybe i am missing something here ?     https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/5301121df4727b357293b3b7de00555362f90170/firebase-config/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/internal/ConfigFetchHandler.java#L153

Comment: @MartinJäkel, you know, I didn't experiment with that version of the library, but tried before (in 2018 year). Because `setConfigSettingsAsync` doesn't depend on dev/release mode, we can use one constant for both (but can use different). As I learnt before, `0L` is not a good value, as it led to bugs. I don't remember them, but probably it synchronized too frequently and eventually did't sync at all or gave failure instead of success in callback.

Comment: @MartinJäkel, see also https://github.com/udacity/and-nd-firebase/issues/61#issuecomment-531669186.

Comment: How is `setDeveloperModeEnabled` related to `setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds `exactly? What does it do? And what is the default value for `setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds ` ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, thanks for the question. `DEFAULT_MINIMUM_FETCH_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = HOURS.toSeconds(12);`. As I understood, during enabled `DeveloperMode` you can read values from `FRC` without any delay (get instant values), so it looks like fetch interval = 0 sec. But there is some difference, because setting the interval to 0 will lead to not synchronizing in the future. That was a possibility to test an application without waiting for fetching new values.

Comment: @CoolMind I see. I think that by naming it "interval", it's between fetches. Not the first one.

Comment: @androiddeveloper, agree with you. I think, on the first run we will receive default values. Maybe on the second run we will get right ones. And after passing fetch interval we will again get new values (if they have changed).

Comment: @CoolMind So what do you use it for debug vs non-debug?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, currently I use this code for both cases, because we seldom change anything in `FRC`. If you want to check faster in debug build, you can use the solution of ConcernedHobbit.

Comment: @CoolMind But if you set it to the default, why bother setting it at all? We have to use `setConfigSettingsAsync` , even if we don't change anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220840/discussion-between-coolmind-and-android-developer).

Answer (score 7):

To supplement CoolMind's answer, I found you have (at least) two options when it comes to setting the minimum fetch interval (setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds). You can either do as CoolMind said when you build your remoteConfig object (in Kotlin):

```
firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
        .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(12))
        .build())
```

or you can set the value within your fetch command as a supplied parameter. This example is also in Kotlin, and I've expanded my code to try and make it very clear what's going on:

```
remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().build())

// Fetch the remote config values from the server at a certain rate. If we are in debug
// mode, fetch every time we create the app. Otherwise, fetch a new value ever X hours.
var minimumFetchInvervalInSeconds = 0
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { 
    minimumFetchInvervalInSeconds = 0 
} else { 
    minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds = TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(12) 
}

val fetch: Task<Void> = remoteConfig.fetch()

fetch.addOnSuccessListener {
    remoteConfig.activate()
    // Update parameter method(s) would be here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you, in build configuration we can change interval to zero.

Comment: Agree with you, looking at https://androidwave.com/firebase-remote-config/ and https://blog.mindorks.com/getting-started-with-firebase-remote-config-in-android, I found that they also had set 0 seconds in debug build.